# Iterate through object and push its arrays inside new object | AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

I have been trying for hours to push all of my coordinates arrays into an object, but I can't seem to find out how to find and push the coordinates array using angular.

I thought I would be able to use angular.forEach to accomplish this, but I can't get it it work. I tried to find the answer and tutorials, but nothing seems to fit my need here. I might not be fully understanding.

Here's my JSON:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          22.5792379347961,
          32.700558883278
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          22.5794856682809,
          34.7005532568414
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my latest attempt:

```
$scope.coordinates = [];
$scope.features = response.data.features;
  angular.forEach($scope.features, function(features){
  angular.forEach(features.geometry, function(geometry){
  $scope.coordinates.push(geometry.coordinates);   
  });
  });
```

Any tutorial references or examples (even better) on how to accomplish this, would be much appreciated!

I am looking for the following result:

```
"coordinates": [
            [22.5792379347961, 32.700558883278],
            [22.5794856682809, 34.7005532568414]
            ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  $scope.coordinates = [];
  $scope.features = response.data.features;
  angular.forEach($scope.features, function(features){
     $scope.coordinates.push(features.geometry.coordinates);   
  });
```

Comment: Jeez, thanks! :D That does it. Still not sure on why that works and mine does not :(

Comment: Geometry is not an array but a json object, you can get your property without iterating through it. Well if it had solved your problem, i guess you should accept the answer.. :-)